# Symfony : Error : Attempted to call function "ctype_digit"

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm experiencing an error while trying to install my Symfony (3.3) project on my server.
I'm using an Apache HTTP Server and PHP 7.0.

When i'm accessing app_dev.php, it shows that error :

```
UndefinedFunctionException

Attempted to call function "ctype_digit" from namespace "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel".

in Kernel.php (line 274)

at Kernel->getName()in Kernel.php (line 85)

at Kernel->__construct('dev', true)in app_dev.php (line 25)
```

My composer update works well.

Does anybody know where it could come from ?
.. or simply has an hint on the way to search.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: is ctype extension enabled?

Comment: Thank you for your response, an idea on how to enable this extension ? I'm not finding anything. And nothing to enable in my php.ini that could be the ctype extension.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ctype.installation.php

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually compiling PHP from sources. I have enabled ctype, but had an error during the compilation process (command : make): Makefile:1112: recipe for target 'main/php_variables.lo' failed
make: *** [main/php_variables.lo] Error 1
Can't resolve this problem right now. :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem fixed. Actually, after **updating PHP 7.0 to 7.1**, it installed the ctype extension that was missing. I don't know why it wasn't already installed and enabled with my PHP 7.0 installation.

Many thanks for your help.