# Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException:

Tags: php, symfony, console, ubuntu-16.04

When I execute any command in console I have this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException: Attempted to call function "ctype_digit" from namespace "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel". in /opt/lampp/htdocs/eSentinelle/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:272
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/eSentinelle/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(83): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->getName()
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/eSentinelle/bin/console(25): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->__construct('dev', true)
#2 {main}
  thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/eSentinelle/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php on line 272
```

And in the meantime I remember I put update my 7.0 php has 7.1 but I don't know if it's the main cause of my mistake... makes ten hours that I searched the net but nothing... a helping hand...

Comment: Update the PHP cli version to 7.1

Comment: Can you post some code snippet?

Comment: @Smaïne my php version is 7.1. When i run 'php -v' i get this: PHP 7.1.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Dec 14 2017 15:37:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

Comment: @Smaïne now when i run **php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup** i get this: **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Composer\Console\json_decode() in /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php:145** .

Comment: @ReynierPM, should what code I post? I said I I'm using Xamp

Comment: @Bel what you've said does not make any sense: the output from the answer to Smaine says that you're using Ubuntu, the answer you are giving to me says you're using XAMP, which one is the right? It's weird though both functions `json_decode()` and `ctype_digit()` are native PHP functions and do not need to enable any extension.

Comment: nvm you can use XAMPP in Linux - I never used it that's why I didn't know about it - certainly you're missing some kind of setup cause you should not get those errors and as for the code to share forget about it since the error is coming from Symfony in both cases which is odd

Comment: OK let me explain, in reality after update my php as @Smaïne said I got this after having run a command: **Error: Call to undefined function Composer\Console\json_decode () in usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php:145** .
now I just uninstall apache2 and php7.1 and I reinstall Xamp, and now when I run a command I have this: **Fatal error: Eception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException: Attempted to call function "ctype_ digit"from namespace"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel". in ../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:272** .

Comment: this guy had your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46054704/symfony-error-attempted-to-call-function-ctype-digit